# Impala: match INT to elements of ARRAY<INT>

Tags: sql, impala

I'd like to select only the rows where an integer is contained by an array (of integers) in Impala and I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT * 
FROM database
WHERE array_contains(ARRAY<INT>, INT)
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array must be joined with the table containing it (or another one), then the WHERE condition works as usual.